# Carbon array of past dates

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, php-carbon

How do I get an array of the last 30 days with Carbon. I tried to generate an array of dates to compare with the database result on dates to fill the gaps where records do not have values

I have this snippet which returns more or less the desired result, but I wonder if there is a better approach

```
  $start = Carbon::now()->subDays(30);
  for ($i = 0 ; $i < 30 ; $i++) {
        $dates[] = $start->copy();
        $start->addDay();
  }

  dd($dates);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got it right. You can shorten it a tiny bit though, by passing `$i` to `addDays`:

```php
$start = Carbon::now()->subDays(30);

for ($i = 0 ; $i <= 30; $i++) {
    $dates[] = $start->copy()->addDays($i);
}
```

---

BTW, a `foreach` with a `range` might be easier to read than a generic `for` loop.

```php
$start = Carbon::now()->subDays(30);

foreach (range(0, 30) as $day) {
    $dates[] = $start->copy()->addDays($day);
}
```

Or even a `map`:

```php
$start = Carbon::now()->subDays(30);

$dates = array_map(fn ($day) => $start->copy()->addDays($day), range(0, 30));
```